# how to convert a string date variable into datetime variable in sas

Tags: datetime, sas

I have a string variable for datetime. Sometimes it is a whole number like 3040000 sometimes a decimal value like this 3130215.123.

I would like to convert this into a date time variable like `mm-dd-yyyy`.

Thanks in advance.

add: I think the value 3130215.123 refers to feb-15-2013 12:30:00.

Comment: These values do not look like SAS datetime (or date) values, which programming language/data-type are you referring to?

Comment: This is from a sas data set. in the contents it says the variable is string with lenght 150. I have never come across a date variable of this format and hence I am lost.

Comment: Do you know where the data came from before it was in the SAS data set?

Comment: Could you add a few more sample values to your question?

Comment: No, The dataset has been downloaded as a sas dataset.               a few data points are:                                      3040211.1
3040211.1109
3040329.0933
3040329.1008

Comment: They look like Julian dates (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day) except the range doesn't match any there (your feb 2013 example doesn't match to anything like the value you quote). They still might be Julian dates with some specific epoch? What domain are these datasets describing?

Comment: I dont know if it can be Julian dates. this is surely a date time variable.

Answer (score 1):

I think these are
3YYMMDD.HHMM

```
3130215.123 -> 3|13|02|15|12|30
```

(the last 0 is assumed).

So, you need:

```
length year month day hour minute second $2;
year=substr(dtvar,2,2);
month=substr(dtvar,4,2);
day=substr(dtvar,6,2);
hour=translate(subpad(dtvar,9,2),'0',' ');
minute=translate(subpad(dtvar,11,2),'0',' ');
second=translate(subpad(dtvar,13,2),'0',' ');
```

then

```
new_dtvar=dhms(mdy(month,day,year),hour,minute,second);
```

Comment: This won't work on the first example (as it had no month/day portion), by the way.

Comment: Yeah, that's a lot better!

Answer (score 0):

Dates, Times, and Datetimes are stored as doubles.  Only the format matters for display.

try

```
var1 = input(var,best.); 

format var1 datetime19.;
```

in a data step to apply the format.  Then look at the results.

Comment: ERROR 48-59: The format $DATETIME was not found or could not be loaded.
 this is the error i get when i use this format.

Comment: edited my post.  Realized you have it as a string, not a number.

Comment: The syntax works without error but the resultant var1 is not correct. It now has only 3 dates 4-Feb-1960 to 6th feb 1960.

Comment: Ok, that just means is is not stored as the number of seconds from 1/1/1960.  You'll need to get a better understand of how that string is created.  Once you know that, you can create the datetime properly.

Answer (score 0):

Based on comments on the original question, the statements would be:

```
format var_date ddmmyyd10. var_time time5. var_datetime datetime19.; 
var_date=input(put(int(17000000+(var)),10.),yymmdd10.);
var_time=input(put((var-int(var))*1e6,z6.),hhmmss6.);
var_datetime=dhms(var_date,hour(var_time),minute(var_time),0);
```

Haven't had a chance to test, so feel free to comment with any errors you get.

Comment: var_date=input(put(int(1700+var),$10.),yymmdd10.);
WARNING: Character format specified for the result of a numeric expression.
527  var_time=input(put(int(var)-var,z4.),time4.);
                                                                ------
                                                                499
ERROR 499-185: Width specified for informat TIME is invalid.

Comment: sorry error again:NOTE: Character values have been converted to numeric
      values at the places given by: (Line):(Column).
      559:29   560:25   560:41
NOTE: Invalid argument to function INPUT at line 559 column 10.

Comment: Sorry, I missed a few zeroes. Can you try again?

Comment: I think you're still off; your time part is not correct for some reason.  At least you need `z6.`, but even that doesn't fix it.  Probably easier to just do the string functions :)

Comment: Yes, it's z6. I was using my phone again...Shouldn't try writing complicated code on the app!

Comment: I fixed it so it seems to work when I test it.  You need to multiply it by a lot more, and you needed to reverse the int(var)-var -> var-int(var), since otherwise you have a negative number that messes with things. If that doesn't do what you were hoping for whatever reason feel free to revert it.

Comment: Yes, and multiplying by 100 would only put the hour part past the decimal point. Cheers @Joe! :)